# Accidental sysprep of AD machine

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, sysprep

Major screw-up here and I need to find out how much trouble I am in.

I have an AD machine that is running Server 2008 R2, hyperv, DHCP and DNS. On the hyperv machine, I have a backup AD instance running along with a handfull of other server 2008 instances.

One of the instances is running Acronis backup which has a current (last night) backup of the hyperv machine.

Sysprep was run on the hyperv machine instead of one of the instances.

What did I lose and what are the basic steps to get back the environment?

Comment: Restore from your last good backup?

Comment: That should be an answer, zoredache :-) Actually, *the* answer...

Comment: I have a good backup using Acronis but I hate to go that route unless I have to. The Acronis software was running on one of the instances.

Comment: @rboarman You really don't have much of a choice at this point.

Comment: Why the down vote? At least leave a comment.

Comment: Are you saying the machine storing your backups is a virtual machine running on the machine it's backing up? When you get this all sorted out, you're going to fix that, right?

Comment: Acronis runs on an instance and backs up to a SAN. In a perfect world, yes, I would have a dedicated machine for backups. This is for a home dev network, so I don't really want to run a separate box just for backups.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a good backup, then try doing a restore of the system state.  Most of what sysprep does is related to that.

Comment: I have to figure out how to run the acronis guest instance, then I can boot from the Acronis CD and restore the machine. I am not sure of Acronis can restore just the system state but I will check. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Is this for a work environment? Because you should be able to replace a smoked VM host without having to depend on what's in it. If the thing was just running AD/DNS/DHCP, then it would be easiest to migrate all of the guests off of it, and just do a plain new install followed by a DCPromo, and then rebuild your DHCP server, hopefully it wasn't too complicated.

Comment: Worst case you can pop the hdd into another host and copy them off manually. Importing them by hand is a pain though because you have to symlink all the XML config files by hand.